# Python Flask app (Telegram Bot) on Heroku not running

Tags: python, flask, heroku

I am using Heroku to host a Telegram Bot script in python using Flask.
I've gone through the process of setting everything up, including the git, the virtual enviroment ( `#py -m venv env` + `#env\Scripts\activate` and the script... It gives no errors but it doesn't run...
I've installed Flask and Gunicorn in the env:

```
#pip install flask
#set FLASK_APP=app.py
#pip install gunicorn
```

FILES IN THE PROJECT:

.gitignore  ->

`env`

Procfile ->

`web: gunicorn deploy:app`

deploy.py ->

```
import os

from flask import Flask, request

import telebot

TOKEN = 'My token here'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)
app = Flask(__name__)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, 'Hello, ' + message.from_user.first_name)


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True, content_types=['text'])
def echo_message(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, message.text)


@app.route('/' + TOKEN, methods=['POST'])
def getMessage():
    bot.process_new_updates([telebot.types.Update.de_json(request.stream.read().decode("utf-8"))])
    return "!", 200


@app.route("/")
def webhook():
    bot.remove_webhook()
    bot.set_webhook(url='My Url here' + TOKEN)
    return "!", 200


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=int(os.environ.get('PORT', 5000)))
```

Comment: Does your code work locally? I can see it running and throwing no errors but does it do functionality wise the things you expect it to? I looked into the PyPI `telebot` module and it looks heavily unfinished.

Comment: mmh.. I tried copying and pasting the code to another folder to run it on my machine... still doesn't work for some reason...
Not sure if you are familiar with any good framework to program telegram bots? (either with Python or javascript or other languages) @TinNguyen
I'm trying to set up a system for Fridays For Future

Comment: P.S. when I edit the code in the deploy.py file, and insert something like only utputting a string in an html format, the code works and gets run, but the code for the python Telegram bot itself doesn't seem to run (I copied and pasted and modified the code present in the API examples of the PyTelegramBotAPI

Comment: I haven't worked with telegram before and I personally don't use telegram. I can't help you there. But the code you have so far is not usable. It won't do what you expect it to do. First the project you are relying on is heavily outdated and second it would never work because they don't mix together since you are depending on two libraries that are blocking each other. Start fresh and use this https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot

Comment: @TinNguyen thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Think problem associated with procfile .first check whether you  add `gunicorn` to `requirements.txt` file or not .According to me instead of using Gunicorn just deploy with Common Procfile .

Try with this  procfile
`Procfile` -- `web : python deploy.py`